# Too many redirect to same page in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to redirect to a the same page if certain conditions are not met in my view in django but i keep getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. I am using HttpResponseRedirect. Will appreciate any help.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


**views.py**
class Test(DetailView):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not .....:
               return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

I have equally tried **return HttpResponseRedirect('')** but it shows a blank screen

Comment: where is your view class or function?

Comment: I updated the question to show the view class.

Comment: i would guess that you are constantly redirecting to the same page

Comment: Yes, constantly redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, something like this (infinite recursion) is happening:

```
def rec(x):
    if not x:     # True when x = 0.
        rec(x)    # Will be called.

rec(0)
```

You need to have some stopping condition.